# How to disable contextmenu item?

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF I have this code for disabling a menuitem on a certain condition:

```
private void gridListPlayers_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    Player player = (Player)gridListPlayers.SelectedItem;

    if(player.Owner.GUID == Guid.Empty.ToString())
    {
        propMenuItem.IsEnabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        propMenuItem.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to achieve the same result of that function via XAML. Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the visibility on or off according to a property in your selected Item.  So create read only property ToggleMenuVisible, which returns (Owner.GUID != Guid.Empty.ToString()) and then in your xaml do something like:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MyToggleMenu"  Header="My Toggle Menu" >
    <MenuItem.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.ToggleMenuVisible}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.ToggleMenuVisible}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Style>
</MenuItem>
```

Obviously you will need to include SelectedItem in your view's model.